# Paginated API in simple terms

Tags: rest, api, pagination

Can some one help me to explain in simple words what is paginated API with an example. How it is used ? and what are the advantages and disadvantages of Paginated API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as a book. You can read it page by page or jump to your favorite line using the page numbers.

Paginated APIs have fields like `nextPage` or `previousPage` with every response to help us navigate through pages.

Pagination makes handling of data easier and faster. Without it, you would feel like you're reading an endless sheet of words.